# How frequent are ledger resets on the public devnet and testnet clusters?

Tags: devnet, testnet, cluster

In the clusters section on the official website: https://docs.solana.com/clusters, both the devnet and testnet have "ledger resets". How frequent are these ledger resets on both the devnet and testnet clusters?

Context: I am planning on running a beta test for a project I am working on and it will span at least two weeks. Knowing the ledger reset schedule would help inform my decision as to which cluster to use for testing

Comment: Devnet and testnet resets are infrequent. In fact, as of 2022-07, the testnet is older than the mainnet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use devnet. Testnet is for testing changes to Solana itself, and runs a different version of Solana than main-net or devnet.